# Python tkinter verify file selected

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter in Python 3.7 as a way to have a user select a file using the askopenfilename window. I also have a "Run" button. I would like to have a check to make sure a file has been opened. If no file is opened, I would like an error message and if a file has been selected, I'd like the program to run.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class GetInfo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.FileLabel = Label(master, text="Open the File to Use", font=("Arial Bold", 13)).grid(row=9, column=0,
                                                                                                  sticky=W)
        openFileCommand = master.register(self.FileOpen)
        self.file_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Select File",
                                      command=openFileCommand).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)

        runCommand = master.register(self.getInput)
        exitCommand = master.register(self.getCancel)

        self.run_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Run",
                                     command=runCommand).grid(row=20, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.cancel_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Cancel",
                                        command=exitCommand).grid(row=20, column=1, sticky=W)

    def FileOpen(self):
        self.File = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open the file",
                                               filetypes=(("Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*")))
        self.file_only = self.File.split('/')[-1]

    def getInput(self):
        if self.File is None:
            self.warning_window = tk.showerror('Error', 'Please select a file to use.')
        else:
            self.close_box_window = tk.messagebox.askokcancel('Running', "Running the program, default = 'ok'")
            if self.close_box_window == True:
                root.destroy()
            else:
                return

    def getCancel(self):

        self.MsgBox_window = tk.messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?", icon="warning",
                                                       default='cancel')
        if self.MsgBox_window == False:
            return
        else:
            root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')
gui = GetInfo(root)

root.mainloop()

File = gui.file_only
```

I keep getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'GetInfo' object has no attribute 'File'
```

I had this working previously (without the if/else check for the self.File code). I'm not sure how to get what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only explanation is that you're calling code that uses that attribute before you set that attribute.

Comment: So is there no way to do what I want to do? Sorry, kind of new to Tkinter and this may be a simple question.

Comment: In your code,I can't find `GenBank_File`.Where is it?

Comment: @Unionicola: I don't know what you mean by that. Of course there's a way to do what you want. You just need to make sure you define `file_only` before you try to use it. By the way, the code you posted does not give the error you say it does.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Sorry about that. I was trying to edit the code to make it more streamlined and missed that reference.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. I'm working to understand Classes better and Tkinter, but I will try to define the variable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems easy,You need to initialize the `File`

```
class GetInfo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.File = None
```

Also, to avoid some careless error, you could use a if statement to judge the filename in the function `FileOpen()`:

```
    def FileOpen(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open the file",
                                               filetypes=(("Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*")))
        if filename: # when cancel, it will be ""
            self.File = filename
            self.file_only = self.File.split('/')[-1]
```